# storing data into firestore in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 arrays like

```
phonenumber[]={12345,67890,43215,34567,56789}
amount[]={10,20,30}
```

I want to store data in a document like

> field1:phonenumber[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmdP.jpg) as 12345 
>     field2:amount[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmdP.jpg) as 10

and again the same process to happen in the same document in firestore.
Is it possible to store like this in firestore

My code

```
    final  int phonenumber[] = {12345,67890,43215,67894,32453};
           final int length = list.length;
         final  int amount[] = {20,30,40,50,60};
          final   int length1 = amount.length;
Map<String, Object> docData1 = new HashMap<>();
                for(int i =0 ; i<length;i++)
                {
                    for(int j =i;j<=i;j++){
                        docData1.put("phonenumber", list[i]);
                        docData1.put("amount", amount[i]);
                    }
                }

                docData1.put("invitee",docData1);
    db.collection("Split").document("lahari")
                            .set(docData1)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document",e);
                                }
                            });
```

error I had occured is

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? if you have any error please edit and update the post

Comment: @sree I have updated my question

Comment: out of memory error in your array list. `length ` and `length1 ` are different in size, that may be the reason

Comment: also your for loop has some problem, check that too

Comment: @sree  I took the same array size can you find the error

Comment: @sree I corrected the for loop logic but again it shows the firebase.firestore.zzk.zza error